# PHP | Curl doesn't always get the data

Tags: php, curl

I have curl code here:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' . $user->steam_id . '/inventory/json/730/2/');
$d=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Sometimes the URL gives me just `null` response. Is there anything possible to do, if it does that, then it will do the request again?

Regards

Comment: Try loading the element into a DOM Object and parse the dom for the specific data $dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $d );

Comment: Put your code in a function. Call the function in your loop. If return null, sleep 1 or 2 seconds and call the function again.

Comment: Have you checked the response codes Curl returns after running exec?  Its entirely possible that a server error or a network error is causing intermittent failures.  You can use curl_getinfo (CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) for HTTP errors and curl_errno () and curl_error () for network errors

Comment: It returns 200 HTTP code and what it shows is just 'null'

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [retry](https://github.com/igorw/retry) package. It's just one function:

```
function retry($retries, callable $fn)
{
    beginning:

    try {
        return $fn();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if (!$retries) {
            throw $e;
        }

        $retries--;

        goto beginning;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
// retry an operation up to 3 times
$response = retry(3, function () use ($user) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' . $user->steam_id . '/inventory/json/730/2/');
    if (!$response = curl_exec($ch)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
});
```